# How I can pass variables from Flex to JavaScript (separate HTML file) and return the other variables?

Tags: javascript, flex4

I need to pass variables from Flex app, process its using the functions and return back to this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check ExternallInterface API

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7fe8.html